# Adding Bcrypt Encoding to Spring MVC Security with limit login attempts

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-bean

I have a working project with limit login attempts i just need to add Bcrypt password encryptation. 
I have the following beans:

```
<beans:bean id="customUserDetailsService"
        class="com.setelog.spring.service.CustomUserDetailsService">
        <beans:property name="usersByUsernameQuery" value="select * from users where username = ?"/>
        <beans:property name="authoritiesByUsernameQuery" value="select username, role from user_roles where username =?" />
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="userDetailsDao" class="com.setelog.spring.dao.UserDetailsDaoImpl" >
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </beans:bean>


    <beans:bean id="authenticationProvider"
        class="com.setelog.spring.handler.LimitLoginAuthenticationProvider">
        <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="customUserDetailsService" />
        <beans:property name="userDetailsDao" ref="userDetailsDao" />
    </beans:bean>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider ref="authenticationProvider" />
    </authentication-manager>
```

I had a project and it had the following which enabled Bcrypt:

```
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="myUserDetailsService" >
        <password-encoder hash="bcrypt" />    
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

But i can't seem to get it working this way. Maybe because of "ref" instead of "user-service-ref" in authentication-provider.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If your `LimitLoginAuthenticationProvider` is a `DaoAuthenticationProvider` you can inject the encoder into that, if it isn't you will have to make it possible in your own custom provider. Wouldn't it be easier to move the limit/lock logic to an `ApplicationListener` which listens for `AbstractAuthenticationFailedEvent`s and that updates a counter in the database (not sure what you r logic exactly does). I assume you use a counter and when a treshold is meet the user is disabled?

Comment: Thanks M. Deinum i posted my answer. Your comment was quite usefull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it! I just had to add an encoder bean to authenticationProvider:

```
<beans:bean id="encoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder"/>


    <beans:bean id="authenticationProvider"
        class="com.setelog.spring.handler.LimitLoginAuthenticationProvider">
        <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="customUserDetailsService" />
        <beans:property name="userDetailsDao" ref="userDetailsDao" />
        <beans:property name="passwordEncoder" ref="encoder" />

    </beans:bean>
```